Warning: loadFont - preEvaluateFont failed: "XRefEntryException: Bad (uncompressed) XRef entry: 4695R"
I am using pdf.js(version 4.4.168) in browser to show some pdf. This is the typescript code look like( using react-pdf "react-pdf": "^9.1.0"):
<div
        id="pdfContainer"
        className={getDynStyles(viewModel)}
        onClick={openPdfUrlLink}
        onScroll={(e) => handlePdfScroll(e)}
      >
        <Document
          options={options}
          file={curPdfUrl}
          onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess}
        >
          {renderPages(numPages)}
        </Document>
      </div>

Today I found part of the pdf could not show in browser:

the brower shows warning log:
Warning: loadFont - preEvaluateFont failed: "XRefEntryException: Bad (uncompressed) XRef entry: 4695R"

it seems the pdf.js load some resource facing some issue. when I download the pdf file and open it using other pdf tools, it works fine, the pdf file are correct. What shoud I do to fixed this issue?

It looks like the PDF file has a defect. Thus, you should fix the PDF file.

using other tool to open the pdf, the font shows normal.

"using other tool to open the pdf, the font shows normal" - so what? (Many PDF tools ignore a large range of errors in PDFs, a tradition started by Adobe Acrobat itself. That doesn't make those broken PDFs valid, though.)

it may be an expert to found out where is the issue of pdf, I am not fimiliar with the pdf standards, it look like the xelatex did not generate the correct xref of document, but it hard to figure out  where is going wrong. the pdf was generated by xelatex

Can you share it?

share what? the pdf file?

"share what? the pdf file?" - yes.

the pdf file was override by the next time compile, when the next time facing this issue, I will share the pdf file to you.
